# Does the latex code “/cdot” represent intersection when dealing with sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably a dumb question but I would just like to confirm if this is true

If I have a set A and B, “$A \cdot B$” would mean the intersection of the 2 sets?

Comment: Usually, "$A\cap B$" is used for the intersection.

Comment: Do you have any more context? It's tough to say what it might mean otherwise. As @Peter points out, $A\cdot B$ would be non-standard notation for the intersection of $A$ and $B$

Comment: I’m going to say the answer is no for most people. You could always define the new notation in the beginning of whatever you’re doing.

Comment: My friend introduced me to Chat GPT so I was using it to verify some of my answers for some questions I was working on and see how accurate it could be. It stated that a dot would be intersection and I have never seen that before so I got curious

Comment: The moral of the story is: Don't trust ChatGPT, especially for math. ChatGPT absolutely sucks at math.

Comment: Technically, I’ve seen dots used for intersection *products* in algebraic geometry or algebraic topology.

Comment: @SmolStrawberry ChatGPT is known to confidently state incorrect facts. It's possible to learn from it, but it's important to keep in mind that what it does is try to complete the chat with the most likely answer according to a dataset, so it will almost never answer "I don't know" unless either it's programmed to do so or "i don't know" is the most common human answer to the specific question in the dataset. And knowing humans, that's rarely the case...

Comment: Yes, according to the very old tradition of [Algebra of Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#LawsThou1854): "The operation of *multiplication* was defined to be what we call intersection... *Addition* was introduced as aggregation when the classes were disjoint."

Comment: Strill in some early modern textbooks on set theory we have that terminology; see e.g. Felix Hausdorff, [Set theory (3rd German ed 1937)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Set_Theory/yvVIdH16k0YC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=felix+Hausdorff,+Set+theory&pg=PA18), page 18: "If $A,B$ are two sets, then by their *sum*, or union $A+B$...by their *intersection* $AB$..."

Comment: Yea I already had my answer but I was interested in how powerful it would be since my friend was hyping it up a lot

Comment: Poor human race ! ChatGPT is another example that too many people are fascinated by every nonsense , if it has anything to do with artificial intelligence. People should return to use their natural intelligence , automatizing everything causes more problems than it solves !

Comment: I mean its pretty interesting and could be used to supplement knowledge for students. Plus curiosity is not a bad thing I would say. That's how we develop our interests